# Nodejs Socket.io: Two(2) kinds of Client with the same listener

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, emit

This is very strange because at one point in my development I had this project running accordingly and now I dont seem to understand why it is acting this way.

Anyway, as mentioned I have to kinds of client, master and guess. So each connection, I have tagging so I can determine which is which, I am good there.

I have a listener that looks like this:

```
 socket.on('START_CHAT', function(response) {.....
     console.log(response);
 });
```

for both client, which they are on different JS file. One for master.js and another for guess.js. At one point on the process both client will signal the server and process data and executes the emit shown below:

```
 socket.emit('START_CHAT', {
      chat_id: newId,
      socket_id: socket.id
 });
```

The problem is that both emit will be received by the Master client. As you can see I added socket.id as part of the data passed. And I was right in my assumption because on the Master-Clients end, I displays two different socket ID, therefore it was the Guess-client's connection.

There is a need for this process because I need to pass that ID and cannot change the emit because I was hoping to have it uniformed to all kind of client.

Why is this happening?

Thank you.